# Replacing list of strings in a string (Objective-c 2.0)

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, replace

For example I'd like to replace all occurrences of @"a" and @"b" in @"abcdabcd" with @"z". I'm currently doing this with repeated called to `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:withString:`:

```
NSString *s1 = @"abcdabcd";
NSString *s2 = [[s1 stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"a" withString:@"z"]
                 stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"b" withString:@"z"];
```

**What's a better way?** I didn't find any similar methods that take an array of strings to replace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
NSString *s2 =
[s1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[ab]"
                              withString:@"z"
                                 options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                   range:NSMakeRange(0, s1.length)];
```

Comment: (If you're targeting OS X 10.7+/iOS 4.0+.)

Answer (score 3):

There's also NSMutableString's [`replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/replaceOccurrencesOfString%3awithString%3aoptions%3arange%3a) method (so you don't have to create a new NSString object for every replacement call you want to make).  Documentation linked for you.